# Swift how to check if file (.plist) exist on the web server

Tags: swift, plist

I have .plist file that is sitting on two different web servers (redundancy). I've done in objective c but how can I do this in swift? Thanks in advance.

// Web Server 1 or Web Server 2
  - (BOOL)MyserverPL
 {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver1.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: NULL];
return ([response statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO;

}

```
    if([self MyserverPL] == YES)
    {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver1.com/playlists/my.plist"]];          
        //  NSLog(@“Web Server 1 up and running");
    }
    else
    {
        //  NSLog(@“Web Server 1 isn’t up and running so go to the Web Server 2");
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver2.com/playlists/my.plist"]];
    }

}
```

Comment: Search for relevant methods in Swift.

Comment: Unrelated but you are strongly discouraged from using `sendSynchronousRequest` – which is deprecated for a very long time –  and synchronous data loading with `initWithContentsOfURL`. Both cause very bad user experience because they block the current thread.

Comment: Thanks, I know my my app is from 2011. So, that is why I need this in swift. So, what should I use instead? How can I do this? Thanks